# Incrementing an Achievement with play-games-plugin-for-unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing a videogame for Android with 32 levels. I wanted to create an Incremental Achievement with 32 steps to show the progress of the game, so every time you finish a level for the first time, I called:

```
((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).IncrementAchievement(
            "id_of_the_achievement", 1, (bool success) => {
                    if(success){
                            int lvlSincs = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LvlSinc");
                            lvlSincs++;
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LvlSinc", lvlSincs);
            }
    });
```

If success I increased a PlayerPrefs variable, so latter I can synchronize the achievements in case that some levels were finished without internet connexion or logged out.

The thing is, if the user finish the first level and then delete the game, the next time he plays the level 1, he will increment the achievement again.

I couldn't find any function to check the current achievement state in this plugin.

Link to the plugin: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Comment: I've never used it but it all seems to be in the documentation on the main page of the link you sent.

Comment: It is in part, but it doesn't work as expected. I think it is because the plugin is not finished yet, but I wondered if someone has found a solution.

The method I posted in the question works fine, but there is no way to find out the current state of the achievement in the google servers and I think that the official API for Android SDK offers this option to solve the problem.

Comment: Hii.. did your achievement get unlocked ? I am facing problem.

Comment: Hi zanky. No, I decided not to use incremental achievements, I used the normal ones.